# Retrieving value from database

Tags: swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I have a problem and would be grateful to any advice or answer.

```
   func getUserProfileMDP(){

    // set attributes to textField
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    print(user!.uid)
    ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String: String] else { return }
        print(value)
        let passwordValue = value["password"]!as! String
        print(passwordValue)
        self.MDP = passwordValue // prints the right value from database

    }){ (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    print(self.MDP) // prints the value innitialised in class(nope)
}
```

Here is the function that gets the value from database. It works (the first print gets the right value)

```
    @IBAction func register(_ sender: Any) {

    print(self.MDP)// prints the value innitialised in class(nope)
    getUserProfileMDP()
    print(self.MDP) // prints the value innitialised in class(nope)
    let MDP = self.MDP
```

That is were I need the password to compare it. It doesn't get me the value of the database but the value initialized in class above:

```
var MDP = "nope"
```

Have a nice day

Comment: Because `.observeSingleEvent` in `getUserProfileMDP()` is asynchronous. So the program control flow is not what you think it is. Use a callback!

Comment: I'm new to swift can you precise what is a "callback"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your last comment, I'd say that you're almost there, but here's an example. I did not fix the other parts of your code, I only added the completion handler in the method signature, and passed the password value to the handler, to show you how this works. The handler must be called inside the async closure.

```
func getUserProfileMDP(completion: @escaping (String)->()) {
    // set attributes to textField
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    print(user!.uid)
    ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String: String] else { return }
        print(value)
        let passwordValue = value["password"]!as! String

        completion(passwordValue)

    }){ (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

And you call it like that:

```
getUserProfileMDP() { pass in
    print(pass)
    self.MDP = pass
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the bother, I have trouble understanding the syntax of this, calling getUserProfileMDP like you wrote it in my @IBAction doesn't solve, the print is still the MDP initialized in the class

Comment: print(self.MDP) should be inside the `{ pass in ...}`, not after.